# How to get specified fields in elasticsearch 5.1 (using curl)?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I want to get specified fields in elasticsearch 5.1 .
For example 
select x,y from table

sample document

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2017.01.05",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVltoGqz-zTtgAXZybOK",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "sourcePORT": "55645",
    "EndTime": "2016-11-08T03:00:43.033",
    "StartTime": "2016-11-08T03:00:43.033",
    "message": "10.215.56.162,55645,161.202.1.13,443,base.ip.tcp,2016-11-08T03:00:43.033,2016-11-08T03:00:43.033,0,74,0.000000,0,0-0:",
    "DestinationPORT": "443",
    "tags": [],
    "path": "C:/Users/akshay.patil/Desktop/DataDump01.csv",
    "DestinationIP": "161.202.1.13",
    "@timestamp": "2017-01-05T07:55:46.710Z",
    "sourceIP": "10.215.56.162",
    "received_at": "2017-01-05T07:55:46.710Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "3299D11",
    "ProtocolPath": "base.ip.tcp"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, you can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) like this:

```
curl localhost:9200/index/type/_search?_source=x,y
```

Comment: Its returning diffrent things like                                                                  {
        "_index": "logstash-2017.01.05",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVltm47D-zTtgAXZvLCn",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {}
       }                                                                                                      but I want actual values present in this field

Comment: You should update your question with the mapping of your `logstash-2017.01.05` index, maybe you have disabled the storage of the source.

Comment: How to enable the storage of source ? What do we need to mention as type in the URL.

Comment: Show your index mapping first using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-2017.01.05`

Comment: Can you show a single document using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-2017.01.05/logs/AVltm47D-zTtgAXZvLCn` ?

Comment: Please update your question with that info, it's not legible in comments

Comment: Can you explain how you're sending your query? via curl?

Comment: GET logstash-2017.01.03/logs/_search?_source=sourceIP

Answer (score 0):

This will return specific field which you want to print

`GET /_search
{"query" : {"match_all": {}}, "docvalue_fields" : ["filed_name"]}`